# How to disintegrate sublist to elements

Tags: python

How can i change a list that has the following elements:

```
days = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', ['Sat', 'Sun']]
```

To:

```
[['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri'], 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

Comment: What are the "rules" for this operation?  Can you input have more than one list nested in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
>>> [[i for i in days if not isinstance(i, list)]] + [i for i in days if isinstance(i, list)][0]
[['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri'], 'Sat', 'Sun']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
temp = []
for i in days:
if isinstance(i, list):
    l.append(temp)
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        l.append(j)
else:
    temp.append(i)
if temp:
     l.append(temp)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri'], 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there don't appear to be any rules to this, how about simply:

```
>>> days = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', ['Sat', 'Sun']]
>>> [days[:-1]] + days[-1]
[['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri'], 'Sat', 'Sun']
>>>
```